# Symfony3: Proper way of persisting multiple objects from the same form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a Field class and a FieldType class associated to it and I want to create a interface where the user can edit the FieldType of all the Fields at once.

So I did the following:

```
protected function createUpdateForm() {     
    $fieldList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Field')->findAll();
    $fieldTypeList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:FieldType')->findAll();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder();
    foreach ($fieldList as $field){
        $form->add($field->getDescription(), ChoiceType::class,
                  ['choices' => $fieldTypeList, 
                   'choice_label' => 'getDescription', 
                   'multiple'=>false, 'expanded'=>true, 
                   'data' => $field->getFieldType()]);
    }       
    $form->add('action', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Update']);
    $form->add('cancel', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Cancel']);

    return $form->getForm();
}
```

It takes all the Fields from the database and creates a Radio group with the FieldTypes as the image shows (just the end of the form):

[image]

So for each Field the user can select the type and update the values.
This is how I am updating the form, and that is what I do not like:

```
foreach ($form->getData() as $fieldType){
    $field = array_shift($fieldList);
    $field->setFieldType($fieldType);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->flush();                   
}
```

It works, but everything look like a bodge, I do not like this. I'm starting with Symfony so I'm not sure, but there should be a better way to create the kind of form I need and persist it. I was trying to create a ColletionType, but it is not working out.

**Does anybody know a better way to do this?**

I have a more complex case that will use a similar logic so I'm trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood you completely, but if I did, this calls for an `CollectionType` as far as I can see it. Plus, if you set the underlying type to be `EntityType` you simplify the things even more.

I think something like this should work:

```
$fieldList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Field')->findAll();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder(['fields' => $fieldList])
    ->add('fields', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => EntityType::class,
        'entry_options' => [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:FieldType',
            'expanded' => true,
            'choice_label' => 'description'
        ]
    ])
    ->add('action', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Update'])
    ->add('cancel', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Cancel'])
    ->getForm();
```

### Update:

```
{{ form_label(form.fields) }}
{% for f in form.fields %}
    {{ form_row(f, {'label': f.vars.value.description}) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Just bare in mind that I currently don't have dev env which I could use to check for typos, but it should work :)

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is actually really close to what I need. It's almost working however I need a way to dynamically set the label of the entry_type as the description of the Field itself. In the image on my question, you can see that the bold text (website, social media) is the Field description. If I just use your code, the label end up as the Field id, but for that to happen I had to set the id property to public for some reason. Sorry if I'm being a bit demanding, but do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Without creating your own type and form rendering customization, that could be tricky. This is because `label` in form type is of `string` type and does not accept `callable`. The update I added above could potentially help you, but it is not ideal.

Comment: It did not work: (Impossible to access an attribute ("description") on a string variable ("1")). The object does not seems to be accessible. Well I guess I'll take a look in creating my own type, but I'm not even sure whether it is a better solution or not, thanks anyway.